# Make small caps for author's last name and & between two authors in my .bst file

Tags: bibliographies, citing, author

I've got a .bst-file and it is almost as I need it. There are two aspects I would like to change but don't know how. Maybe someone could help me:

1) When I want to cite a publication which has two authors it looks like: "Jones, Smith 2018". But I would like it like "Jones & Smith 2018".

2) I would like to use small caps for the author's last names.

The template I use could be downloaded at https://www.geo.uni-augsburg.de/studierende/hinweise/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you consider using `biblatex`? It's easier to customise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `format.lab.names` function in iguastyle_2011-05.bst.

1. Change the `bbl.komma` in line 1576 to `bbl.and`. An alternative method is commenting this line and uncommenting the previous line.
2. Wrap each name with `\textsc{ }`. The final code is as below:

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
   { 's :=
     "" 't :=
     s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
     "\textsc{" swap$ * "}" *      % wrap the name with \textsc{ }
     s num.names$ duplicate$
     #2 >
       { pop$
         " " * bbl.etal *
       }
       { #2 <
           'skip$
           { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
               {
                 " " * bbl.etal *
               }
               { bbl.and space.word * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
                 "\textsc{" swap$ * "}" *      % wrap the name with \textsc{ }
               % { bbl.komma space.word * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
                 * }
             if$
           }
         if$
       }
     if$
   }
   ```

Note that it only changed the style of (short) names in citations. If you want to change the full names in citations (`\citep*`) or in bibliographies, just make similar modifications on `format.full.names` and `format.names`.